# How to attach a function that takes in a parameter for each ItemComponent in iannbing/TreeMenu React?

Tags: reactjs

I would like attach a function to each of the ItemComponent inside the TreeMenu. The catch is that I have to send information about the node to the function. Here's what I've done so far:

```
<TreeMenu data={this.state.dirContents}>
{({ search, items }) => (
    <ul className="List">
        {items.map(({ key, ...props }) => (
            <ItemComponent key={key} {...props} onClick={this.viewItem(props)} />

        ))}
    </ul>
)}
```

I've also tried this:

```
<TreeMenu data={this.state.dirContents} onClickItem>={this.viewItem(someParameterFromTheNode)}
{({ search, items }) => (
    <ul className="List">
        {items.map(({ key, ...props }) => (
            <ItemComponent key={key} {...props} />

        ))}
    </ul>
)}
```

But I have no idea how to pass the node's info to the function.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you expound a little on *I have to send information about the node to the function*?

Comment: For sure, for each ItemComponent inside the TreeMenu, I'd like to pass the node object to the function so i can use it on other components

Comment: Node information like what? You need more than whatever you can get from `even.target`?

Comment: Apparently event.target is enough. Just now needs to highlight that node. Thanks!